# How to get cell values based on matched criteria in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have column A-C in a excel file as given in the picture. My problem is to create a table like that given in column E-G. How can I do that in excel?

[image]

Comment: Please click on "enter image description here" to view the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below macro generates the output in a shape that is depicted on the attached image.

```
'assumptions
'(1) the input data is in columns A,B,C
'(2) the output data is rendered in columns E,F,G
Sub ListByTeacher()
Dim noOfRows As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim c_lv_array(1) As String ' c - course, lv - load value
Dim c As New Collection 'output table with values
Dim k As New Collection 'keys
Dim tmpVar As Variant

'[INPUT]
'identify no of rows with data
i = 1
Do While Len(Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0
    i = i + 1
Loop
noOfRows = i - 1

'Loop through input data rows and build the collection of teachers
For i = 2 To noOfRows
    c_lv_array(0) = Trim(CStr(Cells(i, 1).Value))
    c_lv_array(1) = Trim(CStr(Cells(i, 2).Value))
    On Error Resume Next
    tmpVar = c.Item(Trim(CStr(Cells(i, 3).Value))) 'if teacher in collection
    If IsArray(tmpVar) = True Then 'exists
        If InStr(1, tmpVar(0), c_lv_array(0), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            'c_lv_array(0) = c_lv_array(0) & ", " & tmpVar(0) 'use this line or below one
            c_lv_array(0) = tmpVar(0) & ", " & c_lv_array(0) 'reversed order to the above line
            c_lv_array(1) = CStr(CInt(c_lv_array(1)) + CInt(tmpVar(1)))
        End If
        c.Remove Trim(CStr(Cells(i, 3).Value))
        c.Add Item:=c_lv_array, Key:=Trim(CStr(Cells(i, 3).Value))
    End If
    tmpVar = Empty
    c.Add Item:=c_lv_array, Key:=Trim(CStr(Cells(i, 3).Value))
    k.Add Item:=Trim(CStr(Cells(i, 3).Value)), Key:=Trim(CStr(Cells(i, 3).Value))
Next i

'[OUTPUT]
'Render the result in s/s
Cells(1, 5) = "Teacher"
Cells(1, 6) = "Courses"
Cells(1, 7) = "Load"

j = 2
For i = 1 To c.Count
    tmpVar = c.Item(k.Item(i))
    Cells(j, 5) = k.Item(i)
    Cells(j, 6) = tmpVar(0)
    Cells(j, 7) = tmpVar(1)
    j = j + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Just wondering how to send the output in columns A,B, and C of another existing worksheet named say "TeacherLoad" in the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You should really make a pivot table for this.

This way you will be able to add to the list in column A-C while continuously updating the other viewpoint in E-G.

It does require two things though:

1. To be able to continuously update the values in the pivot table, columns A to C should be turned into a table (`CTRL + L`).
2. The pivot table would have it's own sheet.

Comment: I could manage to get only E and G from information in column A-C with a pivot table, but could not get column F. Moreover, column titles are "Row Labels" and "Sum of Load Value" in the pivot table.